# In C#, what would be a nicer way to show this while loop?

Tags: c#, .net, string, if-statement, while-loop

```
namespace StringProgramFruits
{
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("What is your favourite fruit?, (Apples), (Bananas), (Kiwi) or (Peaches)?");
        string fruit = Console.ReadLine();
        if (fruit == "Apple")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Apples!");
        }
        if (fruit == "Kiwi")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Kiwi!");
        }
        if (fruit == "Bananas")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Bananas!");
        }
        while (fruit != "Apple") while (fruit != "Bananas") while (fruit != "Kiwi")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Try Again!");
                    fruit = Console.ReadLine();
                    if (fruit == "Apple")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Apples!");
                    }
                    if (fruit == "Kiwi")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Kiwi!");
                    }
                    if (fruit == "Bananas")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Bananas!");
                    }
                    return;

                }
    }
}
```

If you look at the while loop there, I just added 3 while functions in a single line to add more conditions. This doesn't look very nice in the code base, so I was wondering if there was a different or easier way to add multiple conditions to while loops. I have tried using

```
while (fruit != "Apple") || (fruit != "Bananas") || (fruit != "Kiwi")
```

but the above code just showed up as an invalid expression :/

It's probably quite apparent that I am very new to C-sharp, and while this is a very trivial question, I would still like to know if there is any other way nonetheless.

EDIT: I now just realised that I needed to place '&&' between the while functions, but by just looking at the refactoring's really shows how code can always be shortened and improved (with switch's, dictionaries etc) and how little I know about the bare basics.

Comment: You should also use a `switch`, which is ideal for these cases, instead of so many ifs, which by the way, are all evaluated even though one of them was true. For this specific case, I would also use a `do-while`. That would allow you not to repeat your conditions.

Comment: Your present code also wouldn't work as is. Imagine the case where first the user enters "Mango" and then "Apple". Your code will be stuck in the innermost loop.

Comment: But you also have a return in the loops. The loops are useless now.

Comment: What @AjayBrahmakshatriya is saying, is that you don't have a loop with three conditions, you have 3 nested loops, each with it's own condition. You break out of all 3 loops with the same line, which happens regardless of any conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code I refactor

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("What is your favourite fruit?, (Apples), (Bananas), (Kiwi) or (Peaches)?");
            string[] words = new string[] { "Apple", "Bananas", "Kiwi" };

            string input = Console.ReadLine();

            while (!words.Contains(input))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Try Again!");
                input = Console.ReadLine();
            }
            Console.WriteLine(input + "!");
        }
```

Comment: Exactly what I was about to post, LOL. The only detail (which I think it doesn't matter) is that for "Apple" he prints "Apples!", so you would need an extra 's' there. ;)

Comment: @Andrew I thing the code (both mine and OP) doesn't mention 'Peaches' the array should have that element too, if that is part of question.

Comment: @AnirudhaGupta I attempted to shorten the code a bit before posting here and forgot to remove 'Peaches' from the array.

Comment: @SamuelQuansah OK, it's clear now.

Comment: Is there a major performance difference with your refactoring vs my original post?

Comment: @SamuelQuansah I am not sure, I will research it tonight and let you know

Comment: @AnirudhaGupta, my message had nothing to do with "Peaches" but with the difference between "Apple" and "Apples".

Comment: @SamuelQuansah, at this level there is absolutely NO sense in worrying about performance. First of all, you have user input, so that will be your only bottleneck. And secondly, the code is so simple that any approach will be extremely fast. If you had to do a similar comparison one million times per second, only then you may want to worry about the faster option.

Comment: @Andrew is correct. I was thinking about Hashset used in another answer when I am travelling on road today but at the end I found the reason is "Difference in fixed array and Hashset is negligible " in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a statement that runs while the user's answer is not Apple, Bananas or Kiwi, so:

```
 while ((fruit != "Apple") && (fruit != "Bananas") && (fruit != "Kiwi"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a refactor to not duplicate the list of fruits. Also it looks like there are some inconsistencies in plural, singular. I made them all singular. Using the HashSet so case insensitive check can be done easily.

```
        HashSet<string> validFruits = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
        { "Apple", "Banana", "Kiwi", "Peach" };

        Console.WriteLine($"What is your favourite fruit? {string.Join(", ", validFruits.Select(f => $"({f})"))}");
        string fruit = Console.ReadLine();

        while (!validFruits.Contains(fruit))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Try Again!");
            fruit = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"{fruit}!");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly simplified version of the one provided by A.Gupta:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("What is your favourite fruit?, (Apples), (Bananas), (Kiwi) or (Peaches)?");
        string[] words = { "Apples", "Bananas", "Kiwi", "Peaches" }; // simple array declaration
        string input = Console.ReadLine();
        while (!words.Contains(input))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Try Again!");
            input = Console.ReadLine();
        }
        Console.WriteLine(input + "!");
        Console.ReadKey(); // optional to let the User read the response
    }
```

Best regards,

Comment: You just removed `new string[]`, added "Peaches" and the `ReadKey`... Is this really a new different answer?